# Jbehave Dependency Causes Error When running

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am having an error that I can't seem to find the answer to how to fix online. When I am running my code I am getting this error here.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] (please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.catalyst.SMA.SmaApplication.main(SmaApplication.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] (please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.checkTemplateLocationExists(FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 17 more
```

The thing is that I know where the issue is coming from. It's from my Behave dependency in the pom file. I tested it by commenting it out and it then runs. Here is my pom file so you can look at it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.catalyst.SMA</groupId>
<artifactId>com.catalyst.SMA</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SMA</name>
<description>Social Media Aggregator</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.exclusions>SmaApplication.java</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Joda Time dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate validator -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Email Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Facebook rest api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring caching -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
        </artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your issue is that JBehave as a dependency on FreeMarker (see [deps on mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-core/4.0.4)) which causes Spring Boots auto configuration to kick in and configure FreeMarker as your template engine. Basically you do have different options to get rid of this issue

1. Do what the error states and add `spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false` to your `application.yml` or `application.properties` to suppress the check for templates location. This still leaves you with the template engine configured
2. Disable Autoconfiguration for FreeMarker by adding the `exclude` option to your `@SpringBootApplication` like this `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={FreeMarkerAutoconfiguration.class})`
3. Create the `templates` folder as expected in resources.
4. Exclude the transient dependency on your JBehave dependency in your pom.xml as described in the documentation of [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Which of those is the right decision depends on your demand and the application, e.g. if you do not need JBehave's HTML or Mail reporting functionality which uses FreeMarker it is most likely safe to go for option 4, in all other cases I personally would use option 2.

**Side notes**

- You should always scope your dependencies properly, e.g. all of your deps for testing should correctly have a `<scope>test</scope>` setting as it is the case for the `spring-boot-starter-test`. That helps to keep the final artifact small.
- I don't see a reason for what you'd need the scala dependency in your setup.
- `logback` is the default logging framework in Spring Boot and does not have to be defined. I'm actually also not 100% sure if it is a really good idea to have two logging libs (log4j and logback) in your setup.
- Is there a special reason why you not used spring-social-facebook but rather `restfb` instead? Does not look consistent to me.
- Additionally I'm wondering about having `spring-data-jpa` dependency in as well as the plain `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`?
- In general you defined a lot of your dependency explicitly whereas they are anyhow provided as a transient dependency of other requirements, e.g. hibernate would be automatically brought in by `spring-data-jpa`.
- I personally would go for version 1.3.2 of spring-boot in your parent relationship definition. It will bring in a lot of new functionalities and should be really non-breaking.